# Java Regex To Grab Last 5 Characters

Tags: java, regex

I have values of varying lengths and I am looking to either grab the last 5 characters, or just the whole word if its less than 5 characters. All through Regex. Here are some examples:

```
JRHG
ARTI
45789
000012345
5679754
JOH12345
000098765
```

I have tried using this Regex, but it is not matching correctly and returns no matches.

`(.{5})$`

Comment: Try with `....$` and refer the above so link.

Answer (score 1):

This  should  work :

```
(.{0,5})$
```

Comment: Still not working but I believe this is the correct answer. I have to dig more into the script to find out why it isn't.

Comment: I recommend using [regexr](https://regexr.com/) for testing Regular Expressions